# Disk space for windows subsystem for linux (in case I have installed 2 WSL distribution)

Tags: ubuntu, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have accidentally installed two distribution of WSL (Ubuntu and Debian apps), with both built some software.

I then realize that the `/home/usr` of the two are independent of each other, eg. I could not use Ubuntu to access the files that I placed in `/home/usr` using Debian. Is it there are different `/home/usr`?

Are there any limitations of disk space allocated to the subsystem? Or we can install programs or data as long as we have disk space in our pc? 
(As previously I used virtual machine and there was a place to let us allocate limited disk storage to them)

And are there any bad consequences if I continue to keep these two WSL distribution on my pc? Or I should delete either one?

Any advice are highly appreciated! Thank you :)

Comment: 1. No limitation of disk space.  2. No bad consequences with two distro.

Comment: thanks @Biswapriyo . There is not yet a problem. But just wanna know, as I cannot access the files in `/home/usr` in one distro when I put the actual files in `/home/usr` of other distro. So the `/home/usr` are different for each distro? Thanks, I am just quite new to these subsystems...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access another distribution files, you have to configure the SSH connections between two distributions. Let you want to access Ubuntu files from Debian. In diagram: `Debian (host) ------> Ubuntu (server)`.

#### Create SSH server in Ubuntu: Follow these commands with `root` user

- Purge OpenSSH-Server package: `apt purge openssh-server`
- Install OpenSSH-Server package: `apt install openssh-server`
- Allow password authentication: `sed -i 's/PasswordAuthentication no/PasswordAuthentication yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
- Create SSH key pair: `ssh-keygen -A`
- Restart sshd service: `service ssh --full-restart`

[image: Ubuntu_Server]

#### Login with Debian SSH client: Install OpenSSH-Server and allow password authentication as above

- Connect with SSH server: `ssh username@localhost`

[image: Debian_Client]

It is recommended not to close command prompt in old Windows 10 builds. Also you can access files with `cd` command. Here are the two root i.e. `/` path of the distributions (XYZ are variables, depends on version):

- Debian: `%LocalAppData%\Pacakges\TheDebianProject.DebianGNULinux_XYZ\LocalState\rootfs`
- Ubuntu: `%LocalAppData%\Pacakges\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows\LocalState\rootfs`

#### Related Links:

- [How to connect from WSL to WSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3325)
- [Location of WSL rootfs filesystem](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2578)

Comment: Hi thanks for this! All steps could run perfectly but I still cannot login to ubuntu (vice versa) with: 
`sudo ssh ubuntu@localhost`. The message is: 
`The authenticity of host 'localhost (127.0.0.1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is xxxxxxx'
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
ubuntu@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.` 
Is it cannot be established? Is the password means ubuntu root's password or ssh password? (seems I haven't set up ssh password...)

Comment: Yep! I have run this command. Yes and it showed: `[ ok ] Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.` in Debian, ` * Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd [ OK ]` in Ubuntu. How can I find the distro of ssh server? Thanks!!

Comment: Ok, and is the `ubuntu@localhost's password:` means the one for root/sudo ? thanks!

Comment: Sudo password. Not root